# System.TypeLoadException when I try to convert JArray to an object in a thread

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, json.net

I have a C# code that converts a JArray object **jsonArray** (JSON.Net) to a list of objects **jsonList** (List< MyClass >):

```
List<MyClass> jsonList = jsonArray.ToObject<List<MyClass>> ();
```

The code above works fine when I run it on the main thread, but if I put the same code inside a different thread, like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate() {
    List<MyClass> jsonList = jsonArray.ToObject<List<MyClass>> ();
});
t.Start();
```

I get the following error message: "System.TypeLoadException has been thrown. A type load exception has occurred".

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? The full stack trace is below. Thanks in advance!

> System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[System.Type,System.Type].AddValue
>   (System.Type key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[System.Type,System.Type].Get
>   (System.Type key) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAssociatedMetadataType
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[JsonContainerAttribute]
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[JsonContainerAttribute]
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider attributeProvider) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonContainerAttribute].AddValue
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2[System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider,Newtonsoft.Json.JsonContainerAttribute].Get
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider key) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CachedAttributeGetter`1[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonContainerAttribute].GetAttribute
>   (ICustomAttributeProvider type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetJsonContainerAttribute
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetJsonObjectAttribute
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe
>   (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean
>   checkAdditionalContent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000]
>   in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader
>   reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) [0x00000] in <filename
>   unknown>:0   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (System.Type
>   objectType, Boolean isNullable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (System.Type objectType)
>   [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject[List`1] () [0x00000] in :0   at GuiaTV.AgoraController.GetJSON () [0x00015] in
>   /Users/vegidio/Documents/Dev/Xamarin/GuiaTV/GuiaTV/Controllers/AgoraController.cs:24
>   at GuiaTV.AgoraScreen.m__2 () [0x0000d] in
>   /Users/vegidio/Documents/Dev/Xamarin/GuiaTV/GuiaTV/Views/AgoraScreen.cs:43
>   at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x0001d] in
>   /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs:697

Comment: Your problem could be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112533/monotouch-with-newtonsoft-not-working

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. Apparently there's a specific version of JSON.Net that works with MonoTouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are developing a touch based applicationfor this you need the latest edition of NewtonSoft for Mono Touch.Get it from [here](https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json).

If you are building it for a modern UI its very easy follow the Win 8 templates or use a Task to initiate the thread.

Try putting in a Try,Catch,Finally block to get the exception details.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was a specific port of JSON.Net in order to work on MonoTouch.

Comment: if u like the answer then you can accept it.Its upto you.Any queries about issues you can ask questions and then only we can put our brains and search techniques of Internet to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint on

```
List<MyClass> jsonList = jsonArray.ToObject<List<MyClass>> ();
```

and hover that breakpoint to look at the inner exception, what does it say?

The reason I ask is because a TypeLoad exception will either throw a null or give you a message on the inner exception that could help you a little more than this stack trace.